# Tensordot - ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 18014398241046529 into shape (134217726, 134217727)

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, reshape, valueerror, dot-product

I am trying to take the dot product of two sparse arrays (implemented as a COO matrix from the pydata sparse library). The code that I have been using to diagnose this problem is:

```
print('Transition matrix type: {}'.format(type(transition)))
print('Transition shape: {}'.format(transition.shape))
print('Transition dtype: {}'.format(transition.dtype))

print('Reward matrix type: {}'.format(type(reward)))
print('Reward shape: {}'.format(reward.shape))
print('Reward dtype: {}'.format(reward.dtype))

n = transition.shape[0]
print(n)
print(np.dot(transition[0:n,0:n], reward[0:n,:]).shape)
```

The shape of the transition matrix is (134217727, 134217727) and the shape of the reward matrix is (134217727, 4). The error is raised after calling reshape from the tensordot function to reshape the transition matrix from it's flattened shape to a shape of (134217726, 134217727). I don't understand why it would even need to first dimension of the transition matrix since the second dimension of the first matrix is what matters to have a valid dot product.

Another thing that I found interesting was that any value of n less than the one computed above allows for the dot product to be computed as expected (this is why the calculation of n and all of the indexing in the dot product is even included at all).

Could someone please help me figure out why the matrix is being reshaped and how I can fix the error?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:
Here is the output and traceback.

```
> Transition matrix type: <class 'sparse._coo.core.COO'>
>     Transition shape: (134217727, 134217727)
>     Transition dtype: float64
>     Reward matrix type: <class 'sparse._coo.core.COO'>
>     Reward shape: (134217727, 4)
>     Reward dtype: int32
>     134217727

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-2840c8dab51a> in <module>
      9 n = transition.shape[0]
     10 print(n)
---> 11 print(np.dot(transition[0:n,0:n], reward[0:n,:]).shape)

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparse\_sparse_array.py in __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
    246             pass
    247         else:
--> 248             return sparse_func(*args, **kwargs)
    249 
    250         try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparse\_common.py in dot(a, b)
    324     if b.ndim == 1:
    325         b_axis = -1
--> 326     return tensordot(a, b, axes=(a_axis, b_axis))
    327 
    328 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparse\_common.py in tensordot(a, b, axes, return_type)
    194         return res
    195 
--> 196     at = a.transpose(newaxes_a).reshape(newshape_a)
    197     bt = b.transpose(newaxes_b).reshape(newshape_b)
    198     res = _dot(at, bt, return_type)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparse\_coo\core.py in reshape(self, shape, order)
   1015 
   1016         if self.size != reduce(operator.mul, shape, 1):
-> 1017             raise ValueError(
   1018                 "cannot reshape array of size {} into shape {}".format(self.size, shape)
   1019             )

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 18014398241046529 into shape (134217726, 134217727)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but `np.dot(A,B)` is not good if either `A` or `B` is a scipy.sparse matrix.  `A*B`, `A@B` or `A.dot(B)` should be used to use the matrix's own matrix multiplication.

Comment: Show the actual `traceback`.  Where's the `tensordot` call?  Show the actual code that's producing the error.  And clearly identify the variables - type, dtype, shape.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj for the suggestions as I was not aware of that. I am still getting a similar traceback and error when using A@B and A.dot(B) compared to the np.dot(A,B). They both call the tensordot and then I get the error in the reshape function. I have also added the traceback to the questions that shows the tensordot call. Thanks again for the help!